# Issue while building xml request in java

Tags: java, xml, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to send an xml request:

This is how I am creating the request:

```
public String getReq(Item item){
    StringBuilder req= new StringBuilder();
    // add the headers and other neccessary parameters

    req.append("<rt:value1>");
    req.append(item.getValue1());
    req.append("</rt:value1>");
    req.append("<rt:value2>");
    req.append(item.getValue2());
    req.append("</rt:value2>");
    // add other neccessary parameters
    return req.toString();
}
```

My Item class is:

```
public class Item{
    String value1;
    String value2;
    public String getValue1() {
        return value1;
    }
    public void setValue1(String value1) {
        this.value1 = value1;
    }
    public String getValue2() {
        return value2;
    }
    public void setValue2(String value2) {
        this.value2 = value2;
    }

}
```

My issue is sometimes I am getting the proper xml request and response, and sometimes the xml request looks like this: 
(This is just the part of the request which is getting wrong)

```
<rt:value1 />
<rt:value2 />
```

it should looks like this :

```
<rt:value1>v123</rt:value1>
<rt:value2>231</rt:value2>
```

I am not able to find the change of the request xml like this.

**Edit:**
I thought it might be because of the null values, so I even tried by changing the Item class as this:

```
    String value1= "";
    String value2= "";
```

Comment: <rt:value1 /> means that your variable value1 is empty/null...

Comment: @AndréSchild but I am appending the tags and the values separately right, how does the appending works in such cases then?

Comment: Sorry, did oversee this. For me it looks like there is another class generating the XML content. Perhaps a default converter taking precedence?

Comment: @AndréSchild what i did was, before sending the request, I checked the request by sysout, that's when I came to know the request is sending as <rt:value1 />

Comment: Is there perhaps a output filter compressing the xml result?

Comment: Your code can never produce the output you claim you are seeing.  You are generating a text string through custom code and the code you have shown has no hard-coded `<rt:value1 />` and `<rt:value2 />`.  See [your code actually running](http://ideone.com/43r6lX) to see the output with different data input.  You have either provided incomplete code or have other pieces of code involved in this.  Also, any specific reason why you want to generate the XML on your own instead of using a serializer such as JAXB?

Comment: Is your code formatting the xml string returned by getReq() method? If the values are empty or null, then formatting the xml might cause this.

Comment: @Tootsie, this question cannot be answered in its current form as there are several issues with it.  The provided code and output do not match so either more details are missing or incorrect code has been provided.  Secondly, the `xmlhttprequest` tag is irrelevant if you believe that the problem is at the end where the XML is being generated and that end uses Java (that tag refers to the JavaScript XMLHttpRequest object).  Please improve the question with more and correct details.